# sftp/ssh connection works on network but not from outside

Tags: networking, router, ssh, port-forwarding, sftp

Okay, this is a weird one. I normally don't ask questions here, but I'm about 5 hours in and my brain is melting.

I have set up a sftp server on my network with the following attributes in my sshd_config file:

```
Match group sftp
ChrootDirectory /home
X11Forwarding no
AllowTcpForwarding no
ForceCommand internal-sftp -d /dataUser/drive1/data/
```

This [works  perfectly  fine](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J7bbA.png) when I use it locally and I can also [connect to the root](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vrKYh.png) user when I connect locally from another PC. The device has the local IP `192.168.0.42`. Let's call this **device A**.
Now I want to use this over the internet, so naturally, I forwarded port 4000 to port 22 on this device:
[port forwarding - left number LAN, right number WAN Port](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H5R1r.png).

Ok. So let's try to connect.
[Error message: Connection timed out](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ww2FG.png)

So is it the port forwarding? I have another Server on WAN port 42069 [that forwards to the LAN IP 31 with Port 22](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h7yZV.png) (and also other ports. They all (just) work). Let's call that **device B**. It works fine. From inside the network and outside.

I also tried to connect to **A** with ssh to the root user instead of sftp to the dataUser. It works on the network, it doesn't work from the outside.

Ok, so I [scanned my Ports with nmap](https://i.stack.imgur.com/APOZ9.png):
Port 42069 goes to **device B** - STATE: open
Port 4000 goes to **device A**  - STATE: filtered

I also tried one of those websites - CanYouSeeMee.org and [apparently my ISP is not blocking](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EJcQ2.png) this port.

So I tried the same with samba file sharing. Same result. It works inside the network, it doesn't from the outside. That Website shows my ISP is not made by the devil to waste my time and nmap shows the state 'filtered'.

I changed the ports multiple times, I deactivated my firewall in the router settings, which I already restarted two times (the same with my Client and Server for that matter).

I really don't know if this is fixable. I have currently given up on this, maybe you can help me.

Comment: Does the device show that it is _receiving_ packets on port 4000 when you try to connect?

Comment: How do I test that?

Comment: By using a packet capture tool, such as tcpdump, Wireshark, or Windows' pktmon.

Comment: It is not quite clear to me if all the trouble is on the same device. If so, check for firewalls on that device.

Comment: Okay @user1686 if I understand correctly, I should Capture Packets from the router IP?

If so, these are the lines received: 

10:04:50.347430 ARP, Request who-has omv tell kabelbox.local, length 46
10:04:50.352059 IP kabelbox.local.domain > omv.54562: 31782* 1/0/1 PTR omv. (71)
10:04:50.354611 IP kabelbox.local.domain > omv.36621: 18350* 1/0/1 PTR kabelbox.local. (81)
10:04:55.470413 ARP, Reply kabelbox.local is-at 48:4e:fc:9e:9b:39 (oui Unknown), length 46
10:04:57.577792 IP kabelbox.local > all-systems.mcast.net: igmp query v3

Comment: @Gantendo Yes, the device with all the trouble is device A in my question. I use ubuntu 20 and I know of only one firewall, ufw, which is disabled.

Comment: No; packets from the internet come from the router's MAC address but **not** from the router's IP address – they come from the original IP address that attempted to connect. (Only 'NAT hairpin' is an exception.) Try the filter `port 22 or 4000`. If you're doing it via SSH, then filtering `(not host <your_PC_LAN_IP>) and (port 22 or 4000)` would avoid the infinite loop of irrelevant packets.

Comment: @Gantendo I don't really know what that is, but I seems to be a sort of subsection of the LAN. And yes, it is. I tried to connect with my phone over Termius + LTE and it worked. So the problem seems to be that I connected from within the network to something in my network, but over a public IP address, if I got that right?
Thanks so much for your help and sorry for wasting my time, this should absolutely have been including in my troubleshooting...

Comment: Thanks, @user1686, for teaching me some networking stuff though :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your router evidently does not support NAT Loopback,
meaning a loop such as:

*PC -> router -> internet -> router -> PC*.

[NAT Loopback/hairpinning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_address_translation#NAT_loopback)
is not supported on many consumer routers.

To connect to your computer via your public IP, you should
connect from outside your local network.
For example, use your phone.

Comment: Just noticed that myself, but you are right. That was the problem.

Answer (score 0):

What router do you have to port forward. Did you use your public IP on a different network.

You need to use another network (say a hotspot with your phone) to access your port forward or else all traffic will go to the router itself.

This works for me on my OpenWRT router

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).